# How to Add Java Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

At work training, I'm writing a Java (in which I have 0 experience) program that should meet the following criteria:

> Write a program that replicates distributed computing application
>
> Create central 'scheduler' object which contains a list of M random numbers
>
> Create N processor threads that retrieve a number from the scheduler then loop that many times before requesting another number
>
> If no numbers are available from the scheduler, wait to request another number.
>
> If no more numbers are left, all the threads should end.

So far, I created an object with an array of random numbers, but I really don't know how to proceed with multithreading.  Could someone please guide me through it?  This is what I have so far, along with comments indicating pseudo code.

```
public class ThreadDemo extends Thread
{
    //create new array of arbitrary size 5
    static int SIZE = 5;
    static int[] myIntArray = new int[SIZE];
    
    
    public ThreadDemo()
    {
        start();
    }
    
    class RunnableThread implements Runnable {

        Thread runner;
        public RunnableThread() {
        }
        public RunnableThread(String threadName) {
            runner = new Thread(this, threadName); // (1) Create a new thread.
            System.out.println(runner.getName());
            runner.start(); // (2) Start the thread.
        }
        public void run() {
            //Display info about this particular thread
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        {
            myIntArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        }
        
        ThreadDemo scheduler = new ThreadDemo();
        
        //create M processor threads that retrieve number from scheduler
            //for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
                //
        
        //if no threads available
            //make the scheduler thread wait() ??
        
        //if empty
            //stop() the scheduler thread ??
        
    }

    }
```

Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: This problem statement is a bit strange. If there are exactly M numbers and M threads then each thread will pick up a number and then terminate. What's the point of the last two constraints?

Comment: Sorry, I had made a typo.  There are actually M random numbers and N processor threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first pointer: don't start threads in a constructor and don't use the `Runnable` object to start a thread using itself. It's very confusing to whoever reads the code.

Here's my take on this problem (hope I didn't get carried away):

```
class Scheduler {
    private int[] numbers;
    private AtomicInteger current = new AtomicInteger();

    public Scheduler(int count) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        numbers = new int[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            numbers[i] = rand.nextInt();
            if(numbers[i] < 0) numbers[i] *= -1;
        }   
    }

    public int getNextNumber() {
        int local = current.incrementAndGet();
        if(local >= numbers.length) {
            return -1;
        }
        return numbers[local];
    }
}
```

First, we define the `Scheduler` class that holds an array of random (positive) integers and returns a number from the array on-demand, based on an atomically incrementing counter.

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private Scheduler scheduler;  

    public Task(Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;     
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {           
            int limit = scheduler.getNextNumber(); // get next number
            if(limit == -1) return; // no more numbers
            System.out.println(limit);
            for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                // spin
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

The `Task` class holds the code that each thread executes. Each thread loops indefinitely requesting numbers from the `Scheduler`, until the array is exhausted.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Scheduler s = new Scheduler(100);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            exec.submit(new Task(s));
        }

        exec.shutdown();
        exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);       
    }
}
```

In the main class we set up a thread pool and execute 4 threads to do the aforementioned tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the tip and explanation. Seeing the problem and code visually laid out helps me understand code better than reference documents do, although both are great resources.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a good place to start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). IT will also help to look at a [executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). [Here](http://sunels.wordpress.com/category/executorservice-example/) is an example.

You might also want to take a look at [some of the concurrent collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). It might be worth using a queue instead of an array so its a little cleaner to tell when something has been pulled out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at te [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

You should end up with something like this.

```
public static void main(){
    ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(...);
    List<Integer> numbers = getNumberList();
    for(Integer i : numbers){
    tpe.submit(new MyRunnable(i) {
            Integer i;
            public MyRunnable(Integer i){
              this.i=i;
            }
        @Override
        public void run() {
         dosomethingWith(i);
        }
      }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your Homework, you need to create a producer and worker thread units. Please refer the below link, which will suits your requirement.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/WorkQueue.html

Thanks
Thanikachalan